# How to make gradle build in android project faster?

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle

Now i have a project. When i build it with ant, it takes only 40 seconds. But when i build it with gradle, it takes me 3 minutes or 4 minutes, which is really to much for me.

How can i fasten my gradle build?

Comment: if it takes that long, i guess the startup time of gradle itself is no problem, right?  have you timed, what tasks are taking actually the longest?

Comment: Building on cfrick's comment, you can accomplish this by adding `--profile` to your Gradle command line which will give you a nice HTML report of configuration and task execution times.

Answer (score 0):

It can help you if you run Gradle in daemon mode - https://twitter.com/timbray/status/512368955516657664

Comment: after i ask this question, i have been refactoring my project. And refactor helps! the build time is decrease from 3.5 mins to 2.5 minutes.   but the article you posted are not really helping. After i config the "org.gradle.daemon", the build time changed to 2 min 13 seconds, which is not very big improvement. What else can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple cores try `gradle --daemon --parallel build`, otherwise if you lack multiple cores try `gradle --daemon --parallel-threads <number of threads you want to spawn> build`. I saw a speed improvement of 200% after the first invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Enable android studio "offline work"

or when use gradle cli, use `./gradlew --offline`