# How to make gradle faster

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

I installed the android sdk and gradle on Windows 8.1.

It is too slow because the build tool takes too much time.

Can I get rid of gradle?

How else can I make it faster?

Comment: There are ways to make it faster. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29726866/4749719).

Answer (score 2):

There are some thing, which could help a bit:

1) In Settings->Build->Compiler and add **Command line options**:

- --offline --parallel

  and **VM options**:
- -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m-          -

2) In the file gradle.properties add line *org.gradle.daemon=true*

3) Give a try to [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#) emulator.

4) Move project to SSD disk. Or flash disk - build time can drop to half.

Last option is not to use AS and Gradle at all. Switch to Eclipse (make new project, move res and src files + import all libraries you using, for example NDK is easier to set up there), but it's also not that "heavy" and up to date as AS, so probably not much helpful after all.